# WKWebView loadFileURL works only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, wkwebview

I need to load a local file in a WKWebView. I'm using the new ios9 method

`- (nullable WKNavigation *)loadFileURL:(NSURL *)URL allowingReadAccessToURL:(NSURL *)readAccessURL`

It works perfectly for the first load (navigation delegation is properly called), but if I try to load a new and different file, it does nothing.

The URL for the currentItem in the wkwebview instance is modified. But if I force a reload the delegate method didFinishNavigation is called with the previous set URL. I also tried to navigate forward but the file that was supposed to be loaded is the current one, it's not on the backForwardList.

The code I'm using to start the WKWebView and load the file:

```
self.wk_webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.wk_webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.wk_webview.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.wk_webview];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:local_path];
[self.wk_webview loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
```

Am I missing something? I couldn't find anything related to this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I had a very similar problem as yours, but in my case I had a reference to WKWebView objects in UIViewCell objects (I have migrated from UIWebView recently).

I was reusing WKWebView objects because of the performance reasons (standard dequeue reusable thing).

To make a long story short, you have a allowingReadAccessToURL parameter in **loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:** method that tells WKWebView what are allowed paths when it loads a local file. From some reason, it doesn't care about this parameter when some page with a different allowingReadAccessToURL parameter is loaded. So I recommend to use the entire Documents path space as a default parameter to this method:

```
NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];
[self loadFileURL:request.URL allowingReadAccessToURL:documentsURL];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not helped me.

Comment: It is quite important to pass the whole directory containing your candidate files to be loaded in the "allowingReadAccessToURL:" , otherwise when you will attempt to load another file in your webView it won't work.

Comment: Worked great for me to pass in the parent directory.

Comment: Anyone on MacOS have success using this, in a sandbox env. vs request loads?

Answer (score 4):

finally! I Know where went wrong!!
When you want to load a new and different file, make sure it's in the same directory as the first load file.

eg.

```
NSString *pathA = "file:///path/to/abc/dirA/A.html";
NSString *pathB = "file:///path/to/abc/dirB/B.html";
NSString *pathC = "file:///path/to/abc/dirC/C.html";


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathA];

NSURL *readAccessToURL = [[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
 // readAccessToURL == "file:///path/to/abc/"

[self.wk_webview loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:readAccessToURL];
// then you want load  pathB
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathB];
// this will work fine
[self.wk_webview loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:readAccessToURL];
```

Comment: I can't test now your answer, but if html files need to be in the same directory, it isn't a proper solution anyway. I ended up using the older uiwebkit api, it works as expected.

Comment: Why everything Apple creates have to be confuse? I am convinced they hate developers. Why not simply add `myWebView.loadURL` ? People who create these APIs there have mental problems.

Comment: it doesn't have to be in the same directory.
BUT... it has to be in the directory which you set as "allowingRadAccessToURL" in the previous call. 
that is a pretty crappy bug IMO. 
so, in my case, I set the allowed directory one up from where my html file was so I could then still load other html files from sibling directories of my first one.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem.  What worked for me is to simply to refresh the UIView container holding the webView:

```
[webView loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
[webViewContainer setNeedsDisplay];
[webViewContainer setNeedsLayout];
```

Hope this helps.