# Sandbox & WKWebView loadFileURL(_, allowingReadAccessTo:) Inconsistency

Tags: macos, wkwebview, appstore-sandbox

Using the new shiny WKWebView and sandbox on os/x, require some intervening reset or clear as subsequent calls to load a file URL will be ignored; this is somewhat related to an earlier question on [WKWebView loadFileURL works only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472796/wkwebview-loadfileurl-works-only-once) - 
 ios there, here on os/X I do

```
if loadURL.isFileURL {
    webView.loadFileURL(loadURL, allowingReadAccessTo: loadURL)
}
else
{
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: loadURL))
}
```

I've tried to pass `loadURL.deletingLastPathComponent()` as the second arg but then all breaks - no file URLs get loaded, nor does using the user's home path, or the entire root `'file:///'`, nor the 'temporary' exception re: absolute file paths.  Finally, trying an intervening topLoading() has no affect.

The only solution (yuck) to get a subsequent file URL loaded is to first load a non file URL!

It seems within a sandbox environment this has unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works but ugly - webView subclass function, as you cannot reuse a webView when a file url was previously loaded.  This workaround will instantiate a new window/doc tossing the old - unless as a user preference they want to keep the old window (newWindows flag is true):

```
func loadNext(url: URL) {
    let doc = self.window?.windowController?.document as! Document
    let newWindows = UserSettings.createNewWindows.value
    var fileURL = url

    if !url.isFileURL {
        if newWindows {
            do
            {
                let next = try NSDocumentController.shared().openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay(true) as! Document
                let oldWindow = self.window
                let newWindow = next.windowControllers.first?.window
                (newWindow?.contentView?.subviews.first as! MyWebView).load(URLRequest(url: url))
                newWindow?.offsetFromWindow(oldWindow!)
            }
            catch let error {
                NSApp.presentError(error)
                Swift.print("Yoink, unable to create new url doc for (\(url))")
                return
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }

    if let origURL = (fileURL as NSURL).resolvedFinderAlias() {
        fileURL = origURL
    }

    if appDelegate.isSandboxed() && !appDelegate.storeBookmark(url: fileURL) {
        Swift.print("Yoink, unable to sandbox \(fileURL))")
        return
    }

    if !(self.url?.isFileURL)! && !newWindows {
        self.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
        doc.update(to: fileURL, ofType: fileURL.pathExtension)
        return
    }

    //  We need or want a new window; if need, remove the old afterward
    do {
        let next = try NSDocumentController.shared().openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay(true) as! Document
        let oldWindow = doc.windowControllers.first?.window
        let newWindow = next.windowControllers.first?.window
        (newWindow?.contentView?.subviews.first as! MyWebView).loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: fileURL)
        if newWindows {
            newWindow?.offsetFromWindow(oldWindow!)
        }
        else
        {
            newWindow?.overlayWindow(oldWindow!)
            oldWindow?.orderOut(self)
        }
        next.update(to: fileURL, ofType: fileURL.pathExtension)
    }
    catch let error
    {
        NSApp.presentError(error)
        Swift.print("Yoink, unable to new doc (\(fileURL))")
    }
}
```